# cannot get value using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have hidden field to store the value and bind the value in javascript aswell, and now it pops a problem as my server doesnt support 4.0 either its in 3.5 so it doesnt support ClientIDmode property , please find code below

```
<asp:HiddenField ID ="lbl1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
```

Javascript:

```
function sourceval() {
         var src1 = window.document.getElementById('lbl1').value;           
    }
```

if i use literal it has visibility property where the rendering of the page would be problem , please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need the `ClientIDMode`, you can simply access the element by its generated `ClientID`:

```
function sourceval() {
    var src1 = window.document.getElementById('<%= lbl1.ClientID %>').value;           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The DOM element ID will not be the same as the server control ID if the ClientIDMode is not static, which is a feature debuted in .NET 4. I think this is happening here. The proposed solutions are...

1. If your Javascript is written on the same ASPX/ASCX

   var src1=document.getElementById('<%= lbl1.ClientID%>');
2. If you are on external Javascript, then add a class to the hidden field and use JQuery to select by class

   var src1=$('.youHiddenFieldClass').val();
   or in plain Javascript like

   document.getElementsByClassName('classname')

Comment: The result of #1 is an element reference, the result of #2 is a string value. Given that the [W3C Selector API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/) is supported by pretty much all browsers in use and the OP has not included a jQuery tag, it would be better to propose a non–jQuery answer, like: `document.querySelectorAll('.youHiddenFieldClass')[0].value`. However, that should be feature tested first.